# Sync two rtsp stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, rtsp, capture

Before creating the post I did several searches on the web without finding a solution to my problem.

I have to capture two rtsp streams from 2 ipcam to be analyzed later with opencv. I use a raspberry and the low power of calculation does not allow me to carry out the analysis on the two 1080p video streams with opencv in real time. So I thought to capture the two streams with raspberry and analyze them later with a more powerful machine.

Commands used for capture:

```
ffmpeg -stimeout 2000000 -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.131/h264 -c copy -f mp4 -y out1.mp4
ffmpeg -stimeout 2000000 -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.132/h264 -c copy -f mp4 -y out2.mp4
```

The problem is that the two rtsp streams captured in two files out1.mp4 and out2.mp4 are never perfectly synchronized. The delay is about 1 second variable, and represents a problem for me. I believe that the latency of communication with the camera can affect the delay.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No experience with this at all (hence just a comment). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol): *RTP carries real-time data. Information provided by this protocol include timestamps (for synchronization)*. From the [`ffmpeg` manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): *When there are multiple input files, `ffmpeg` tries to keep them synchronized by tracking lowest timestamp on any active input stream*. Are the cameras synchronized? (I expect NTP). Have you tried capturing both streams with a single `ffmpeg` to a single container that supports multiple streams?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried capturing in single file with the command: 

`ffmpeg -stimeout 2000000 -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.5.131/h264 -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.5.132/h264 -map 0 -map 1 -c copy - f mpegts -y out.ts`

 But the problem of syncronization persists. Yes the cameras are syncronized with the same NTP settings

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting

`-stimeout 2000000 -re -rtsp_transport tcp`

ffmpeg usually does a better job of figuring things out than we do!

setting video pts with

`-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)'[v1];[1:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)'[v2]"`

From the ffmpeg documentation
 https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-139:
 (some documentation says this is deprecated but I am using the November 27th build and it works.)

you will then need to re-encode the video

`-map '[v1]' -map '[v2]' -map a -c:v libx265 -c:a copy`

So for you last command line it would look like this:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.5.131/h264 \
-i rtsp://192.168.5.132/h264 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)'[v1]; \
 [1:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)'[v2]" \
-map '[v1]' -map '[v2]' -map a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f mpegts -y out.ts`

YMMV, but it works with my cheap Chinese IP cams